# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager vs. PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, http, connection-pooling

`org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`
`org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager`

What is the difference between these two types?
Which one is more reliable in a multithreaded environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between these two types?

[`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) maintains a pool of [`HttpClientConnection`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpClientConnection.html)s, which provides synchronous/blocking communication.

[`PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/conn/PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.html) maintains a pool of [`NHttpClientConnection`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/apidocs/org/apache/http/nio/NHttpClientConnection.html)s, which provides asynchronous/non-blocking and event driven communication.

> Which one is more reliable in a multithreaded environment?

Both types are annotated with [`@Contract`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/annotation/Contract.html) which has an element to indicate the [threading behavior enforced at runtime](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/annotation/ThreadingBehavior.html).

[`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) is annotated with `@Contract(threading=SAFE_CONDITIONAL)` which indicates it's thread-safe *if* the dependencies injected at construction time are thread-safe.

[`PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/conn/PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.html) is annotated with `@Contract(threading=SAFE)`, so it can be considered fully thread-safe.

Comment: I was trying to decide which is the most suitable type to be used when using `AsyncRestTemplate` (and `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`) - 
but it seems that actually just the second one is eligible as the `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` connection-manger, which expects `NHttpClientConnectionManager`