# Google cloud java api client http connection pool

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am creating default connection for google cloud storage and big query:

```
BigQueryOptions
.getDefaultInstance()
.getService()
```

and

```
StorageOptions
.getDefaultInstance()
.getService()
```

I am using these libs:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
     <version>1.55.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>1.88.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

I plan to use single big-query and storage java client in multiple threads.

Are these clients thread safe? what is default size of http connection pool? Can we change the size of http connection pool?

Comment: Before asking about the undocumented internals of SDKs, I suggest explaining what you're hoping to accomplish. The best solution might not have anything to do with what you assume about the SDKs.  (The SDKs are open source, so you can actually see for yourself what they do, and change them if they don't suit your needs.)

Comment: Specify which SDK and version you are referring to. Unless explicit in the documentation, do not assume thread safe.

Comment: I am using bigquery 1.88.0 and storage 1.55.0. What I want to accomplish is to use a single storage and bigquery client between multiple threads. I am wondering if the clients are thread safe and can be long lived. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these clients thread safe?

If you use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` is annotated with `@Contract(threading=SAFE_CONDITIONAL)` which indicates it's thread-safe if the dependencies injected at construction time are thread-safe.

> What is the default size of the HTTP connection pool?'

Per default when using `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` this implementation will create no more than than 2 concurrent connections per given route and no more 20 connections in total, as stated [here.](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html)

> Can we change the size of HTTP connection pool?

Yes you could actually change the size of the HTTP connection pool by following this example, posted in [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/6444).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean default client aren't thread safe and can't be share across multiple threads?

Comment: As mentioned in my last response, if you use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`, only it will be thread-safe if the dependencies at construction time are thread-safe. If you would like to consider other options, you could check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217135/poolinghttpclientconnectionmanager-vs-poolingnhttpclientconnectionmanager) where it talks more in depth the different pool connections. I hope it helps.